# How to pivot dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
StID          SubClassID   PhOrder     PhAmt        LbOrder      LbAmt
4326          200572288    Anti1       23.3         Asprin       13.7
4326          200572288    Anti2       39.3         Morphin      2.2
4326          200572288    NULL        NULL         Medine       30.5
4326          200572288    Anti3       13.5         Kabomin      20.3
4326          200572288    NULL        NULL         Zorifin      0.2
0993          200348299    Anti1       8.4          Zorifin      9.7
0993          200348299    Anti2       10.9         Zorifin      95.6
0993          200348299    Anti4       48.9         NULL         NULL
```

I want to flat this table using one hot encoding

so it looks like this

```
StID          SubClassID   Anti1 Anti2 Anti3 Anti4 Asprin  Morphin Medine Kabomin Zorifin
4326          200572288    23.3  39.3  13.5  NULL  13.7    2.2     30.5   20.3    0.2
0993          200348299    8.4   10.9  NULL  48.9  NULL    NULL    NULL   NULL    52.65
```

Here is the code I did but I get many duplicated columns with wrong values

```
data = {
    'StId': [4326, 4326, 4326, 4326, 4326, 993, 993, 993],
    'SubClassID': [200572288, 200572288, 200572288, 200572288, 200572288, 200348299, 200348299, 200348299],
    'PhOrder': ['Anti1', 'Anti2', 'NULL', 'Anti3', 'NULL', 'Anti1', 'Anti2', 'Anti4'],
    'PhAmt': [23.3, 39.3, None, 13.5, None, 8.4, 10.9, 48.9],
    'LbOrder': ['Asprin', 'Morphin', 'Medine', 'Kabomin', 'Zorifin', 'Zorifin', 'Zorifin', None],
    'LbAmt': [13.7, 2.2, 30.5, 20.3, 0.2, 9.7, 95.6, None]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_pivot = df.pivot_table(index=['StId', 'SubClassID'], columns=['PhOrder','LbOrder'], values=['PhAmt','LbAmt'], aggfunc='first')
```

Comment: Can you clarify the expected output? Since you have amounts, I imagine a sum would be appropriate, if you please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
df1 = df.pivot_table(index=["StId", "SubClassID"], columns="PhOrder", values="PhAmt")
df2 = df.pivot_table(index=["StId", "SubClassID"], columns="LbOrder", values="LbAmt")
print(pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).reset_index())
```

Prints:

```
   StId  SubClassID  Anti1  Anti2  Anti3  Anti4  Asprin  Kabomin  Medine  Morphin  Zorifin
0   993   200348299    8.4   10.9    NaN   48.9     NaN      NaN     NaN      NaN    52.65
1  4326   200572288   23.3   39.3   13.5    NaN    13.7     20.3    30.5      2.2     0.20
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is a problem of aggregation, I used aggfunc='first' but I used NaN, how to avoid NaNs and get the first non-Nan value?

Comment: @asmgx Can you please [edit] your question and put there additional example that produces wrong value?

Answer (score 2):

A generic way to apprehend this operation would be to [`lreshape`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.lreshape.html), then [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
out = (pd.lreshape(df, {'col': ['PhOrder', 'LbOrder'], 
                        'value': ['PhAmt', 'LbAmt']})
         .pivot_table(index=['StId', 'SubClassID'], columns='col',
                      values='value', aggfunc='sum')
         .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
      )
```

Output:

```
   StId  SubClassID  Anti1  Anti2  Anti3  Anti4  Asprin  Kabomin  Medine  Morphin  Zorifin
0   993   200348299    8.4   10.9    NaN   48.9     NaN      NaN     NaN      NaN    105.3
1  4326   200572288   23.3   39.3   13.5    NaN    13.7     20.3    30.5      2.2      0.2
```